# Triggering on time segments with TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In a table of events, I have a column that gets populated with the number of seconds since the last event was recorded for particular users.   The first event time is obviously null since no previous events exist (desc order):

```
9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b    9   2012-01-12 00:05:56.890
9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b    11  2012-01-12 00:05:47.097
9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b    10  2012-01-12 00:05:36.713
9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b    6   2012-01-12 00:05:26.963
9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b    NULL    2012-01-12 00:05:20.500
```

I have another table where I have some trigger values.  For example, 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 90 seconds with a trigger value that I want to read when each target is hit.

After an event is recorded, I have a query that checks to see if the trigger time has been exceeded:

```
SELECT TriggerValue, SUM(p.LastEventTimeSpan)
FROM PageVisitEvents p RIGHT JOIN Segments s ON p.CampaignID = s.CampaignID
WHERE p.VisitorID = '9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b'
GROUP BY TriggerValue
```

This works great if I only want to trigger on one time.  However the query above returns the following (trigger value) total time):

```
30  357
60  357
90  357
```

With one value, doing a comparison is just fine, however my comparison now only shows 90 when this time has been exceeded, and nothing in between.

When each trigger is met, I would like to return only for that trigger.  For example when the time in between events hits 35 seconds, only return the trigger value for 30, and not that of 10 seconds.

Can I get some suggestions on how to tackle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever,

I see what you're saying about expensive, and I'd like to stay away from a lot of joins, so I stuck them in a view, did a subquery on that:

```
SELECT TOP (1) TriggerValue
FROM dbo.vw_CombinedView
WHERE SegmentID = 2
AND TriggerValue < (
    SELECT SUM(p.LastEventTimeSpan) AS TotalTime
    FROM PageVisitEvents p
        WHERE p.VisitorID = '9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b'
    )
ORDER BY TriggerValue DESC
```

So far this seems to work for numeric values.  However I'm going to run into an issue where I will be doing this for words in a 'contains' type of scenario.  I may modify your method above for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the trigger values are coming from `Segments`. First, let's separate the summing of values in the `PageVisitEvents` table from the matching to the `Segments` table. We could do that with a subquery or a CTE, I've picked a CTE (and called it `SummedEvents`).

Then, we need to find the matching row in `Segments` that has the highest trigger value below the sum. We could do that in one of a few ways, my preferred way is to do an anti-join. You could use a `TOP/ORDER BY`, but that only works when exactly one result is required.

So, we have:

```
;WITH SummedEvents as (
    SELECT VisitorID,SUM(LastEventTimeSpan) as TotalSpan from PageVisitEvents
    GROUP BY VisitorID
)
SELECT
    TriggerValue,TotalSpan
FROM
    SummedEvents se
        inner join
    Segments s
        on
            se.TotalSpan > s.TriggerValue
        left join
    Segments s_anti
        on
            se.TotalSpan > s_anti.TriggerValue and
            s_anti.TriggerValue > a.TriggerValue
WHERE
    se.VisitorID = '9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b' AND
    s_anti.TriggerValue is null
```

The anti-join is a combination of the left join to `s_anti` (where we try to find a better matching row from `Segments` than the one in `s`), and the `WHERE` clause filter `s_anti.TriggerValue is null` which ensures that the left join was unsuccessful.

You may worry that the CTE is going to be expensive, and compute the sum for all `VisitorID` values. It may be (if SQL Server is being especially dumb), but generally it should identify that it can filter to just the `9fb63b905a004106bd26c80a5caec52b` rows and only compute one row. But I've done it this way because the shape of the above query will be more generally usable for other queries. But if performance is poor, move the first `WHERE` clause condition up into the CTE and see if that improves matters.

Comment: May use this later on, but a bit expensive, as you mentioned... see above.